# HttpWebRequest: Too many automatic redirections (302 Moved Temporarily)

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, system.net.httpwebrequest

I try to download some web pages from a "program TV" site, it worked before but now something has changed and impossible to download a page from this site, the url is: https://www.programme-tv.net/programme/chaines-tv.html

This is my code:

```
//url = https://www.programme-tv.net/programme/chaines-tv.html

public async Task<PageResponse> GetPage(string url, int repeat = 0, string moreInfoForLog = null)
        {
            PageResponse pageResponse = new PageResponse();
            

            Thread.Sleep(100);

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 30000;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += TlsValidationCallback;

            string result = null;
            HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            try
            {
                webReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                webReq.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                webReq.KeepAlive = true;
                webReq.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 50;
                webReq.ConnectionGroupName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                webReq.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
                webReq.Method = "GET";
                webReq.UserAgent = GetUserAgent(); //get random user Agent from another method
                webReq.Accept = "ext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                webReq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.8,es-ES;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
                webReq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8");
                webReq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");

                using (WebResponse response = await webReq.GetResponseAsync())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                        result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        pageResponse.Html = result;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                HttpWebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                if (errorResponse != null && errorResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound || ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ConnectionClosed)
                {
                    pageResponse.isError = true;
                    pageResponse.Message = $"NOT FOUND {url}: {ex.Message}";
                    _log.Debug(pageResponse.Message);
                }
                else if (repeat < 5 && errorResponse != null && (errorResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect || errorResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently))
                {
                    url = errorResponse.Headers["Location"];
                    return await GetPage(url, repeat, moreInfoForLog);
                }
                else if (repeat < 5)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    repeat++;
                    return await GetPage(url, repeat, moreInfoForLog);
                }
                else
                {
                    pageResponse.isError = true;
                    pageResponse.Message = $"WEB EXCEPTION ERROR {url} tried 5 times: {ex.Message}";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (repeat < 5)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    repeat++;
                    return await GetPage(url, repeat, moreInfoForLog);
                }
                else
                {
                    pageResponse.isError = true;
                    pageResponse.Message = $"GENERAL ERROR {url} tried 5 times: {ex.Message}";

                }
            }
            return pageResponse;
        }

        private bool TlsValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate CACert, X509Chain CAChain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            if ((sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None))
                return true;

            X509Certificate2 _Certificate = new X509Certificate2(CACert);

            CAChain.Build(_Certificate);
            foreach (X509ChainStatus CACStatus in CAChain.ChainStatus)
            {
                if ((CACStatus.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError) & (CACStatus.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

The method GetPage return a simple object:

```
    public class PageResponse
    {
        public string Html { get; set; }
        public bool isError { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Now the error returning is always:

> Too many automatic redirections were attempted.

I read all tickets here on stackoverflow about this error but no one helps me, I tried everything !!

Thanks for your help, I'm curious if you can find a solution ! :)